# How to retrieve particular row data from mysql through android Volley or JSON?

Tags: android, mysql, json

Hi guys i have already made login and register using volley library and data gets saved successfully as shown in the snap 1 below. Now my question is how to retrieve particular or specific row data for the particular user when he/she logins?? For example if user admin gets logged in how to fetch her entire row alone
saved data in server side
[image: saved data in server side]

Comment: I am also fetching the same problem here is the question [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38142573/how-to-retrieve-particular-row-data-from-server-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    if(isset($conn))
    {
        mysql_select_db('your_db', $conn);
    }
    else
    {
       echo 'Sorry,can not connect to database' ;
    }

   $userid = isset($_GET['id']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) :  "";
   $qur = mysql_query("select usename,other_fields from `your_tbl` where userid= $userid");
 $result =array();
    while($r = mysql_fetch_array($qur)){
extract($r);
       $result[] = array("usename" => $usename,"other_fields" => $other_fields); 
}
$json =array("data"=>$result);
mysql_close($conn);
/* Output header */
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: Here it is php file which will give you table data wrapped in json object.
Now you need to catch that json object through volley get method.
i simply gave you idea how to deal with json object in android.
It's depends on you how you use json object.
This is just simple idea to deal with php json and android.
I hope you will get my language.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use server side scripting. Webservice that will fetch that particular row of data. 
The script should take your input parameters and give you the out put in Json Array or Object.

You then hit this script using volley and the response you receive can then be utilized for the next step.

Answer (score 0):

//call volley get method and get data in success method

```
public void onSuccess(string response) 
{
                try {
                        String s = new String(response);
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);

                       if (jsonObject.has("data")) {
                           JSONArray country =jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                           for (int i = 0; i < country.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject cnt = country.getJSONObject(i);
                            String res=cnt.getString("username"));
                           //now you can use res as per your requirement
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```